# What are the two gate leads on a thyristor?

Tags: power, thyristor, scr

I have a simple question: what is the second gate lead on a power thyristor (see the figure below) ? What is it physically attached to ?

[image: Power thyristor with two small gate leads]

I understood that the thyristor turns on when you force a small current pulse into the gate.
So I don't understand what is the purpose of the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thin red lead is actually a cathode lead. It is used for triggering or squelching the device independent of the high-capacity cathode lead.

Comment: Which cathode is it? Is this thyristor a GTO then ?

Comment: It's the same cathode as the thick red lead.

Comment: if you are extra sure please consider editing the second picture caption here then http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thyristor
honestly I trust you more than wikipedia but I really can't make the edit myself since I am not sure of the correct answer.

Comment: All I could find was [this](http://www.darrahelectric.com/uploads/techLib/IB1152-Troubleshooting-Silicon-Controlled-Rectifiers(SCR%27s)__633821542922955648.pdf), a bit slim on info itself.

Answer (score 1):

One of the two leads goes to the gate. The other is connected as closely as possible to the cathode at the die.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZHnii.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So even if a voltage appears across the cathode lead it won't affect the gate-to-cathode trigger voltage.